# ModelState.IsValid is always returning false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Users user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

`ModelState.IsValid` is always false.
so it just return view and new record is not getting added..

**Edit**

User:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")] [DataType(DataType.Password)] 
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } 
    public string Designation { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "Date of Join")] [DataType(DataType.Date)] public DateTime DOJ { get; set; } 
    public string Email { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")] public System.Int64 PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code for your Users model and your View? It'll help the community workout the problem

Comment: @user1697789. Make sure there are no null entries in the model for non null properties. Also, did you try my answer?

Comment: We need your view. And add this view to your initial question, not in comments.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`ModelState.IsValid` will be false if the validation for the Model failed.

1. You have [DataAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which failed the incoming model.
2. You added custom validations.
3. Make sure there are no null entries in the model for non null properties

Check the `ModelState.Errors` for what is the reason causing this. You can use this:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

Comment: is this code to be wriiten inside if(ModelState.IsValid)

Comment: @user1697789. No, it's a simple code to give you the error in the modelState, put it above the `if (ModelSatate.IsValid)`.

Comment: +1 for var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

Comment: Paste `ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).ElementAt(0);` into the `immediate window`.

Comment: Is this still supposed to work? "errors" is null for me, but I just looked at the ModelState in the debugger, I could view the errors directly.