# ASP.NET MVC - Unrequired server-side validation is firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to save records with server-side validations and MetaData class, this is working correctly with an exception.
Classes that i'm using are Database Model classes and I added a MetaData Class in which I specified validations.
Now, when I try to validate specified Model with DataAnnotations, one field withouth "Required" DataAnnotation is firing as Required.

```
public class ClientesMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    public string AliasCliente;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Razón Social")]
    public string RazonSocial;

    [Range(9999999999, 100000000000, ErrorMessage = "El CUIT debe tener 11 dígitos.")]
    [Required]
    public long CUIT;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Teléfono Corporativo")]
    public string TelefonoCorporativo;

    [Required]
    public int Provincia;

    [Required]
    public int Localidad;

    [Required]
    public string Calle;

    [Required]
    public string Altura;

    [Required]
    public string Piso;

}

//Asociation with Entity Model
[MetadataType(typeof(ClientesMetaData))]
public partial class Clientes
{
    //Excluise Model Properties
    public string ProvinciaString { get; set; }
    public string LocalidadString { get; set; }
}
```

(Fields validated)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJLwn.png

(Error thrown. From first field "IdCliente" NOT specified in MetaData Class)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9PdI.png

Validation Summary
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLh0F.png

---

Edit:
Client Entity Model

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFw5d.png

Comment: I think your IdClient is the key of your database model and by default key is required, can you share the database model for client?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad there's the update in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an initialization issue.
I needed to initialize Clientes model sending it from View(model) method.

[ModelState.IsValid is always returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373935/modelstate-isvalid-is-always-returning-false)